# Whenever I run the code I get two different windows, I don't understand why. Can anyone please find the problem in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import login
sql=login.signandlog()

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        MainMenu(self)
        container=tk.Frame()
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        #dictionay of frames
        self.frames={}
        for i in (a,C,b):
            frame=i(container,self)
            self.frames[i]=frame
            frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.show_frame(a)
    def show_frame(self,context):
        frame=self.frames[context]
        frame.tkraise()

class a(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        print(1)
        #tk.Label(text='kdhkjhfks').pack()
        tk.Button(self,text='show profile',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(b)).pack()

class b(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        print(2)
        d={'c':1,'d':2,'s':3,'7':4,'ds':5,'fhds':6}
        fr=tk.Frame(self)
        fr.columnconfigure([0,1,2],weight=1)
        fr.rowconfigure([0,1,2],weight=1)
        o=d.items()
        k=[[key,value] for key,value in o]
        x=0#row
        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                if x!=len(k):
                    l='{}:{}'.format(k[x][0],k[x][1])
                    tk.Label(master=fr,text=l).grid(column=j,row=i,sticky=tk.NSEW)
                    x+=1
                else:
                    pass
        fr.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
class C(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        page_two =tk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(b))
        page_two.pack()
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self,master):
        menubar =tk.Menu(master)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="log_out", command=master.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="log", menu=filemenu)
        master.config(menu=menubar)     



l=app()
l.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is one of those fairly rare cases where a screenshot might help to make your question clearer.

Comment: What does `login` do

Comment: If you remove `sql=login.signandlog()`, do you still get two windows? Perhaps it is that function which is creating a window.